# Laravel 5.5 and Vue.js

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I've read quite a few docs and tutorials but I'm still not understanding what I'm doing wrong.  I've tried rebuilding the simple component several times with no luck. I'm getting the following errors:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in data(): "ReferenceError: products is not defined"

found in

---> <Products> at resources/assets/js/components/Products.vue
       <Root>
app.js:19613:7
ReferenceError: products is not defined

[Vue warn]: Property or method "data" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

found in

---> <Products> at resources/assets/js/components/Products.vue
       <Root>
app.js:19613:7
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: _vm.data is undefined"

found in

---> <Products> at resources/assets/js/components/Products.vue
       <Root>
```

Here's my `app.js` file:

```
window.Vue = require('vue');

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */

Vue.component('products', require('./components/Products.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '.main-container',
    data: {
        products: []
    }
});
```

and here's the `Products.vue`:

```
<template>
<div class="row">
    <div class="columns large-3 medium-6" v-for="product in data.products" :key="product.product_key">
            <div class="card">
            <div class="card-divider">
                @{{ product.title }}
            </div>
                <a :href="product.product_key" target="_blank"><img :src="product.image"></a>
            <div class="card-section">
                <p>@{{ product.product_description }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data: function () {
            return products
        },
        mounted () {
            this.getProducts();
        },
        methods: {
            getProducts() {
                axios.get('/products/').then((response) => {
                this.products = response.data.results;
                }).catch( error => { console.log(error); });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I know I've probably confused the `.vue` file with some of the properties I was attempting to set in the `app.js`-- can anyone set me straight on how the data should be accessed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `Products.vue` from:

```
data: function () {
   return products
},
```

To

```
data() {
    return {
        products: [],
    }
}
```

There is a difference when it comes to setting the data() object when it's either in the Vue Root object or when it's in components.

In your case, you shouldn't put `return products` in `app.js`. The `products` object will exist in that `Products.vue` component and can be accessed by `this.products`.

Comment: Thanks! That was the problem!